# How to configure AWS to enable sso with OpenAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, openam

I am trying to enable single signon for AWS by configuring OpenAM as the IDP. Is it possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

It looks possible.

Following the [salesforce integration guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-AWS) it looks like the same concepts apply. To get the required meta data, this [blog post](http://blogs.forgerock.org/petermajor/2010/09/how-to-access-federation-metadata-from-browser/) says how to get the metadata.  I tested as far as uploading the meta data, which worked fine, but I haven't tried going all the way through the process.